# Supporting these bit twiddling operations for larger datatypes

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, long-integer, biginteger

I found a nice Java implementation of bit twiddling techniques [here](https://github.com/Waxolunist/bittwiddling/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vcollaborate/bitwise/BinaryUtils.java), for which I think many are based on [that document](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). For in particular the `toBitSet` and `nextPermutation`, I wonder: Is it possible to make them support datatypes that can go beyond 64 bits (`long`)? And how?
Would it be possible to define such methods for Java's `BigInt` for example?

Or would iterating over the *k*-bit binary strings (of length *n*) (where *k* = #bits set to 1, *n* = #bits in total), as `nextPermutation` is doing, necessitate a (slower) `String` implementation (i.e. represent the binary numbers as *n*-character strings)?

Below is the source of the aforementioned operations. I'm sorry for not being able to add more information, I regret to admit that I have little knowledge of bitwise operations in general.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

***toBitSet:***

```
/**
 * Converts {@code value} into a {@link BitSet} of size {@code size}.
 */
public static final BitSet toBitSet(final int size, final long value) {
  BitSet bits = new BitSet(size);
  int idx = 0;
  long tmp = value;
  while (tmp != 0L) {
    if (tmp % 2L != 0L) {
      bits.set(idx);
    }
    ++idx;
    tmp = tmp >>> 1;
  }
  return bits;
}
```

***nextPermutation:***

```
/**
 * Compute the lexicographically next bit permutation.
 * 
 * Suppose we have a pattern of N bits set to 1 in an integer and we want the next permutation of
 * N 1 bits in a lexicographical sense. For example, if N is 3 and the bit pattern is 00010011,
 * the next patterns would be 00010101, 00010110, 00011001,00011010, 00011100, 00100011, and so
 * forth.
 */
 public static final long nextPermutation(long val) {
   long tmp = val | (val - 1);
   return (tmp + 1) | (((-tmp & -~tmp) - 1) >> (Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(val) + 1));
 }
```

Comment: You are supposed to make an effort to do this yourself. Please examine the documentation for the `BigInteger` and `BitSet`? classes, make an effort at this yourself, and if you get stuck at some specific problem, then ask your question.